# how to delete multiple rows using spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am trying to delete multiple row using below method of but this is giving some exception.
If any other alternative available for doing same JOB then please suggest.

```html
deleteByCompositIdIn(List<CompositId> compositIdList)

<----- CompositId class given below ---->

@Embeddable
    public class CompositId {

        @Column(name="empFirstName")
        private String empFirstName;

        @Column(name="empId")
        private int empId;

        public String getEmpFirstName() {
            return empFirstName;
        }

        public void setEmpFirstName(String empFirstName) {
            this.empFirstName = empFirstName;
        }

        public int getEmpId() {
            return empId;
        }

        public void setEmpId(int empId) {
            this.empId = empId;
        }


    }
```

but getting below exception

```html
failed: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
```

Comment: As the exception states you have no transaction. There is no your code so can't suggest proper way. E.g. you can mark the method as @Transactional

Comment: This might help you check out....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821579/transactionrequiredexception-executing-an-update-delete-query

Comment: Post code for function `deleteByCompositIdIn(List<CompositId> compositIdList)`

Comment: Can you please add your spring config? Especially the entityManager definition.

@YagneshAgola The code is generated by Spring Data, I don't think the problem lies there.