# javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm making a game with Spring MVC. I have a method for get the game and update but when it goes to update it gives an error, this is the code:

HomeController.class

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/partida/{idPartida}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPartida(@PathVariable("idPartida") long idPartida,
        Model model) throws IOException {
    Partida p = ServicioAplicacionPartida.getPartida(entityManager,
            idPartida);

    if (p.getJson() == null) {
        p.inicializarPartida(entityManager);
        ServicioAplicacionPartida.update(entityManager, p);
    }
```

GameDAO.class

```
@Transactional
public static Partida update(EntityManager entityManager, Partida p) {
    try {               
        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("update Partida p SET p.json=:json where p.id=:id");
        q.setParameter("json", p.getJson());
        q.setParameter("id", p.getId());
        q.executeUpdate();
        return entityManager.find(Partida.class, p.getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The error occurs when the line "q.executeUdate()" is executed, here it is:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement

And this is the server error:

Estado HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

What can i do to fix it?

Comment: See Drew Corvin's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821579/transactionrequiredexception-executing-an-update-delete-query

Answer (score 0):

You have annotated controller and DAO methods as @Transactional, it is not correct as @Transactional can be inherited to the inner methods. Usually transaction should start at service layer.

Try adding these parameters to @Transactional annotation and remove it from either Controller or DAO.:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

Comment: Thanks it works, now don’t give me error on the server but does not update. I get the following error: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Comment: have you added transactionManager in your config file

Comment: Yes, I checked and is added