# Transactions issues with spring scheduler & spring batch item writer

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions, spring-scheduled

I am trying to run a spring batch job using the `@Scheduled` annotation as follows:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * ?")
public void launchMessageDigestMailing() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    jobLauncher.run(messagesDigestMailingJob, new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("execution_date", new Date()).toJobParameters());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

However, this error does not occur when I launch the job from a spring mvc controller as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/messageDigestMailing")
public void launchMessageDigestMailing() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    jobLauncher.run(messagesDigestMailingJob, new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("execution_date", new Date()).toJobParameters());
}
```

I understand Spring batch manages the transactions and does not require a `@Transactional` / `@EnableTransactionManagement`. Why then do I get the above exception?

All samples I have found on the web use a `ResourcelessTransactionManager` (see https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-and-spring-taskscheduler-example) but I do need for my job executions to be persisted to database.

Can someone please help?

**edit**: Here is the stack trace (you can see the spring batch `ItemWriter` is referred below):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.markMessagesAsNotificationSent(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at com.bignibou.writer.MessagesDigestMailerItemWriter.write(MessagesDigestMailerItemWriter.java:49) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$3.doWithRetry(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286) ~[spring-retry-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
        ... 48 common frames omitted
```

**edit 2**: When I try to enable transactions with `@EnableTransactionManagement` and:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * ?")
@Transactional
public void launchMessageDigestMailing() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    jobLauncher.run(messagesDigestMailingJob, new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("execution_date", new Date()).toJobParameters());
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
2017-05-20 17:04:04.013 ERROR 5574 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again (e.g. remove @Transactional annotations from client).
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:168) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.bignibou.scheduler.Scheduler.launchMessageDigestMailing(Scheduler.java:33) ~[main/:na]
        at com.bignibou.scheduler.Scheduler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f0615234.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at com.bignibou.scheduler.Scheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$26d7d986.launchMessageDigestMailing(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

**edit 3**: Here is my reader configuration:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public static ItemReader<UserAccount> jpaPagingItemReader(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    final JpaPagingItemReader<UserAccount> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
    reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    reader.setQueryString("SELECT ua FROM UserAccount ua JOIN FETCH ua.receivedMessages msg " +
            "WHERE msg.notificationSent = false AND msg.messageRead = false AND ua.enabled = true AND ua.emailNotification = true");
    return reader;
}
```

Comment: so you get first exception when not using `@Transactional` on writer?

Comment: @SabirKhan I get the first exception when I don't use `@Transactional` at all. And the second when I annotate the `@Scheduled` method with `@Transactional`.

Comment: How is your reader and transaction manager configured?

Comment: @MichaelMinella, I have not configured any transaction manager explicitly. I am adding the reader configuration as an edit.

Comment: You need to for JPA.  You need to use the JPA transaction manager.

Comment: @MichaelMinella Thanks for your input.  I forgot to mention that I use spring boot which autoconfigures a `JpaTransactionManager` for me. Do you confirm I am required to **explicitely** configure a `JpaTransactionManager`? Also please note that I don't get the exception above when I run the job through the controller, only when the scheduler is used... What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: I would confirm that the correct transaction manager is being used.  You can use the `--debug` option or the `/beans` accuator endpoint to verify.  Using it without the scheduler, if you are using the session per request pattern, you'd have a transaction created that way anyways (aka outside of batch).

Comment: Umm. Thanks. What you say about the transaction been created by the web layer is interesting... Bear with me whilst I confirm that the correct tx manager is used. I'll update shortly.

Comment: @MichaelMinella, thanks a lot Michael. That was indeed the issue. I have posted an answer taking into account your comments and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Michael Minella's advice of inspecting the configured beans (`/beans` endpoint), I noticed that the configured & declared Transaction Manager, named `transactionManager` is not of type `JpaTransactionManager`. See below:

```
{
"bean": "transactionManager",
"aliases": [],
"scope": "singleton",
"type": "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121",
"resource": "class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]",
"dependencies": [],
},
```

So I configured a `JpaTransactionManager` as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class TransactionManagerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

and the issue was sorted. Note that I did not use any of the `@Transactional` or `@EnableTransactionManagement` in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used JPA in my batch writers so I am not sure what might be causing it but two pointers,

1.Do you really need this cron expression in scheduler?

```
* * * * * ?
```

Its like telling - keep launching new job instances all the time, without any break or am I missing something?

I think, you should try to introduce some time gap in between launches and change your cron expression accordingly.

2.There are questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821579/transactionrequiredexception-executing-an-update-delete-query) and as pointed in first answer, there might be a conflict in container managed and application managed transactions. I guess, you are running your job in some container too. Try to put relevant portions of writer code throwing exception.

Comment: Hi Sabir. The above cron expression is just here for dev/debug purposes. It won't make it to production :-)

Comment: As far as point 2 is concerned, I find it odd that the job can be launched from the controller without problems but that the same code won't work from a `@Scheduled` method. Do you see my point? Any idea?