# Java Hibernate Create Native Query javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this problem, using native query on Hibernate. This the query :

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"UPDATE InvoiceItems SET current_balance = '"+current_balance+"' WHERE record_id = '"+record_id+"'");
query.executeUpdate();
```

but i get this error when run the query :

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query

any suggest ? i have try with this way : [TransactionRequiredException Executing an update/delete query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821579/transactionrequiredexception-executing-an-update-delete-query)

Comment: `record_id` is not an Integer?

Comment: iam use integer

Comment: Then why do the queries treat the fields as text fields? And why aren't you using parameterized queries? Maybe start with a tutorial, as you seem to have a lot of things wrong.

Comment: have try with set parameterized, but still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a transaction.

```
Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction();
Query updateQuery = session.createQuery("UPDATE Post p SET p.title = ?1, p.body = ?2 WHERE p.id = ?3");
updateQuery.setParameter(1, title);
updateQuery.setParameter(2, body);
updateQuery.setParameter(3, id);
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
txn.commit();
```

from https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-transaction-required-exception