# calling a transactional method twice resulting in error

Tags: java, spring, transactions

When I call the below method twice it results in "`javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query`" error. I confirm that the first-time error is not there only when the method call is complete i'm calling this method.

the import used is "org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;"
For the first time this method "TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()" return true and the second time it returns false.

I have followed all the approaches present in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821579/transactionrequiredexception-executing-an-update-delete-query" but none helped.

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void upgradeToSuperUser(UserBO userToBeMadeSuperUser, UserBO loggedInUser) {
System.out.println("Transactional Message  "+TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
    
        javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager
                .createNativeQuery("Update USER SET ROLE='SUPERUSER' where ID=:newSuperUserId");
        query.setParameter("newSuperUserId", userToBeMadeSuperUser.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();

        javax.persistence.Query query0 = entityManager
                .createNativeQuery("Update USER SET ROLE='TEACHER' where ID=:oldSuperUserId");
        query0.setParameter("oldSuperUserId", loggedInUser.getId());
        query0.executeUpdate();
```

edit 1:-
From where its called this method is written in action class

```
public String SuUser() {
        UserBO userToBeMadeSuperUser = userManager.getUserByRefId(userRefID);
        UserBO currentSuperUser = userManager
                .findSuperUserForLoggedInUser(userToBeMadeSuperUser
                        .getSchoolBO().getId());
        if (Role.getValue(currentSuperUser.getRole()).equals(
                Role.getValue(Role.SUPERUSER))
                && Role.getValue(userToBeMadeSuperUser.getRole()).equals(
                        Role.getValue(Role.TEACHER))) {
            userManager.upgradeToSuperUser(userToBeMadeSuperUser,
                    currentSuperUser);
```

EDIT 2:-
I'm upgrading my spring 3 to 5, hibernate 3 to 5  with aspectj version v1.8.10.

```
<aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and my appContext.xml for transactions looks like

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory"
            ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

EDIT 3:-
entity manager in appContext.xml

```
<bean id="entityManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory"
                ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>
```

Comment: Can you please tell if you need to call the method twice immediately? Or just that you are calling the method multiple times?

Comment: @hermit I'm calling the method multiple times

Comment: @hermit can you please have a look

Comment: @Rod Could you post the code that calls this method?

Comment: @Joan i have added the code don't think it will be much help as its a simple method call

Comment: @Rob, your question is not clear if you don't also put the 2nd invocation to `userManager.upgradeToSuperUser(...)`

Comment: @Adrian I'm manually calling this method twice; suppose there are multiple users and I'm calling to make the users upgrade to superuser one by one. The same error occurs when I delete multiple users. Also, after restarting the server the error goes away once and then occurs again when called a second time. I think the transaction are not able to create or destroy, i'm upgrading my application from hibernate 3 to 5, spring 3 to 5 and and earlier it was working fine

Comment: I am still not sure if "calling twice" means in one thread sequentially, or in multiple threads in parallel (e.g. originated from multiple calls of a web service endpoint). The meaning of "manually calling this method twice" is very cryptic without the code shown.

Comment: @HonzaZidek, they are sequential threads, for example suppose on the web i clicked a hyperlink that calls the method once, and when the execution is completed and i tried ti click on the hyperlink again then this error occurs. Please let me know if anything else is needed

Comment: If the action is triggered from web by clicking on a hyperlink, then almost for sure it is running in another thread and as such it is not strictly sequential. Have you checked if my answer is applicable to your case?

Comment: @HonzaZidek, i checked your answer but its not applicable please check the edit 2  in the original post

Comment: How are you creating the entity manager? @Rob. Is the entity manager application managed or container managed?

Comment: @hermit, its container-managed, added edit 3

Comment: Can you try autowiring the entity manager directly if you are creating  itfrom from xml configurations. something this: @PersistenceContext private final EntityManager entityManager;

Comment: yes already autowired with @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

Comment: @hermit i just found that in one class i'm using import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional and in another i'm using javax.transaction.Transactional can a project have both the imports in different classes

Comment: removing the additional javax.transaction.Transactionaj also didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show properly *how* you call the incriminated `upgradeToSuperUser()` transactional method. However as it is the most typical error, I strongly suspect that you are calling it within the same object as it is defined.

In this case, the `@Transactional` annotation is not effective. The Spring default is Spring AOP, which causes that the Spring-generated proxy objects call its own methods internally without the proxy code, so the `@Transactional` decoration is ignored.

You will find more detailed description e.g. here: [Spring @Transaction method call by the method within the same class, does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3423972/2886891)

Comment: Hello, it is true that spring AOP (with both JDK and CGLIB proxy) doesn't support self Invocation.
But Transaction management can handle self-invocation using @EnableTransactionManagement(mode=aspectj) instead of (mode=proxy (default)).
So, as the used mode in the code is aspectJ. it supports indeed the self Invocation.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you mentioned **mode=aspectJ** In order to handle Self-Invocation which is good.
However, you did mention also ***proxy-target-class=true***, which is irrelevant and with no sense.

*Explanation :*

Transaction management supports two modes of handling :

- **mode = proxy** , in this case, and like spring AOP's theory : either JDK proxy or CGLIB proxy is created depending on the target class.
  However, we may enforce the usage of CGLIB proxy each time by precising the proxy-target-class =true.
- **mode = aspectJ** , this mode is supporting self-invocation. In this case, Spring is not creating proxies around your beans; instead, it's modifying the bytecode of the actual bean class, which means that **proxy-target-class=true** or **proxy-target-class=false** won't have any effect because no proxies are involved.

So, make sure to enable the **aspectJ mode** following these steps :

1. ```
   @EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.AspectJ).
   ```
2. *add **spring-aspects** dependency to pom.xml*
3. *add **aspectj-maven-plugin to your pomxml*